# How to count overflow-y hidden class

Tags: jquery

In jquery, how to count overflow-y hidden div class ? I tried to used this but it only count numbers of `hide()`

```
$(".classname > *").filter(":hidden").size();
```

How can I count in `overflow-y: hidden`?

Comment: share your markup sample

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var length = $(".classname > *").filter(function() {
  return this.style.overflowY == "hidden"
}).size();
alert(length);
```

The thing is `:hidden` is a selector which is used to check if any dom node is not visible in the screen.

But you want to see how many elements in a particular object has the css property of `overflow-y:hidden;`.

So this is a css property so you have two ways:

in javascript use `.style.overflowY`:

```
elem.style.overflowY == "hidden"
```

and using jquery:

```
$(this).css('overflow-y') == "hidden"
```

```js
var length = $(".clas > *").filter(function() {
  return this.style.overflowY == "hidden"
}).size();
alert(length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clas'>
  <p style='overflow-y:hidden;'></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p style='overflow-y:hidden;'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following html mark-up

```
<style>
    .className
    {
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
</style>
<div class="className">div1</div>
<div class="className">div2</div>
<div class="className" style="overflow-y:auto">div3</div>
<div class="className" style="overflow-y:auto">div4</div>
<div class="className">div5</div>
<div class="className">div6</div>
```

Then your jQuery code should look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($('div.className').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('overflow-y') == 'hidden';
    }).size());
});
```

If you have the following mark-up without any class specification

```
<div style="overflow-y:hidden">div1</div>
<div style="overflow-y:hidden">div2</div>
<div style="overflow-y:auto">div3</div>
<div style="overflow-y:auto">div4</div>
<div style="overflow-y:hidden">div5</div>
<div style="overflow-y:hidden">div6</div>
```

Simply remove `.className` from `$('div.className')` selector. And your code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('overflow-y') == 'hidden';
    }).size());
});
```

**EDIT**

The above approach applies to parent element only. If you need a selector for **children only**, simply use

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($('div.className > *').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('overflow-y') == 'hidden';
    }).size());
});
```

If you need a selector for the **parent and children**, you can use something like

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($('div.className, div.className *').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('overflow-y') == 'hidden';
    }).size());
});
```